# Did Oscar Wilde declare his genius to a customs officer?

Tags: quotes

A famous quote atributed to Oscar Wilde is that, when he was asked by a customs officer in New York if he had anything to declare, he answered:

> I have nothing to declare except my genius.

Does this have any corroboration?

Comment: Heh, yes I was wondering the same thing. Why would someone so "genius" say something so arrogant? And who quoted him on it?

Comment: @Bizorke-- Being a genius does not necessarily connote humility.

Comment: @mmr True, but being a smartass does.

Comment: This somehow reminds me of the fantastic novel by [Luigi Pirandello](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luigi_Pirandello) "La patente" (The license).

Comment: Perfectly in sync with Wilde's prose.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

'Transatlantic Voyages and Sociology: The Migration and Development of Ideas' By Cherry Schrecker ([Google Books](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=iTH_M9ZZjDwC&lpg=PA129&ots=gvNuZtagv9&dq=I%20have%20nothing%20to%20declare%20except%20my%20genius&pg=PA129#v=onepage&q=I%20have%20nothing%20to%20declare%20except%20my%20genius&f=false)) gives the date as 2 January 1882, and the actual quote as

> I have nothing to declare **but** my genius

<sup>(My emphasis)</sup>

Schrecker cites the book 'Oscar Wilde' by Richard Ellman (1988) and another source as 'Bradbury 1995', but having no access the the actual Schrecker book, this reference remains sketchy.

Comment: Can you expand this to a full answer?